# I have to troubleshoot to connect to internet

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, laptop

Whenever I turn my laptop on, it says it cannot connect to the internet; the bars at the bottom right have a little red cross over them.  I then have to click on that and troubleshoot it.  It always says the problem is that the wireless capability isn't enabled.  I then click, 'fix this' and it does, and I can carry on surfing the internet, but when I turn my laptop of and on again, I have to do this all over again.

I have tried going into the control panel to fix it, using the little blue antenna icon, going into the mobility center. None of it works, or if it does, only for the time I have the laptop on.

It's so frustrating but I can't find where to fix it for good. It's a relatively newish laptop and has done this since day 1. (July 2013)

I don't know what laptop it is as it was a custom-made online. Model number is W251EU running Windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for that, 
1) do one thing reinstall your drivers.
2) try the trouble shooter program of windows.

there might be your problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

This could down to your power management. Try:

1. Network Connections
2. Right click on the wireless connection
3. Click Configure next to the wireless adapter
4. Power Management tab
5. Uncheck "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure everything is set to "automatic" in **Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) Properties** of your wireless network interface card.

[image]

If that doesn't work, you should try to disable and enable wireless network interface card.

If still not working, please give information of `ipconfig`